# value out of range with specific number

Tags: mysql, sql

I defined inside my table an integer of `DECIMAL(5,3)` when I save this type of value: `4.500` all works well, but sometimes, the value is like this: `300` and `Mysql` return value out of range. Should I increase the lenght?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting "value out of range with specific number" you have defined your column as:

```
DECIMAL(5,3)
```

It mean, it can accept the values from -99.999 to 99.999.

Explain:

The first parameter for DECIMAL called PRECISION and second SCALE.

The integer place of precision will be reduced from "5" to "2" because SCALE reserved "3" places in the precision.

So, you have to increase your DECIMAL length.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should increase the length.  The value should be big enough to store what you need:

```
alter table t modify column col decimal(10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the original value in this way

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name decimal(10,5);
```

> For example 5 to give more space for your requirments; also I comment
>   to you this is the data type more exactly to storage numeric data
>   mainly in prices data